# Typescript Decorators before class instance

Tags: typescript, webpack, decorator, typescript-decorator, reflect-metadata

Iam playing around with Typescript decorators and everything is quite good working when I have instanciated a class. 
With the following code, my Class-decorator gets called: 
`import { MyClass } from "./MyClass";
const myClass = new MyClass();`

But when I dont instanciate the class explicit like in the example above, no decorators are called. For example, this module: https://github.com/xrobert35/es-mapping-ts relies on such a structure to save all classes in a storage and generate a mapping. I tried it without instanciating the classes first and generate a mapping, but it does not work either. **Is there any Webpack or Typescript configuration that has to be set to get decorators executed before instanciating the classes where the decorators are placed?** In my state of knowledge and in some online tutorials it is defined that class decorators are called when the class is defined and not when the class is instanciated. 
Cheers!

Comment: decorators are called when the method (or instantiation) happens, not when it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace original class constructor with a class level decorator to do all kinds of cool stuff:

```
function example(target: any) {
    // save a reference to the original constructor
    const original = target;

    // the new constructor behaviour
    const f: any = function (...args: any[]) {
        console.log("Hook before original constructor...");

        const newArgs = [...args].reverse();

        const instance = new original(...newArgs);

        console.log("Hook after original constructor...");

        instance.d = 'ddd';

        return instance;
    }

    // copy prototype so intanceof operator still works
    f.prototype = original.prototype;

    // return new constructor (will override original)
    return f;
}

@example
class SomeClass {
    constructor(public a: number, public b: number, public c: number) {
        console.log("Hello from constructor!")
    }
}

const instance1 = new SomeClass(1, 2, 3);
console.log(instance1); // SomeClass {a: 3, b: 2, c: 1, d: "ddd"}
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=66#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCinQCcBzZKALkXTAE8BKRAbwFgAoRbxAel8QBndADdktRCWTBkUyOKhxEUABbi4JGGRhh0uRBASCoJENA2ceBo1EQatOvYgC8y0hSgBuTpZ79laohgyADu1mDGpuYkiABGyCqi8CAkvtyGEbbANHT0LoigkLAIiAQAdBXugjkMANoAuszsXFY8GYJw%20GW4cGQEAEQAEnBwANZx0hrqmtq6%20u0mZookFWX9jN4caa0LQaEAguSC%20bWrVfVlUmIkgoQbPi2t4caIOsZ0EOKuwWH2s3rlCo-Q5kQT3LaPHZGTrIbq9AbDMa0YBQWR2GaOeY2KLLVbrTbbKxvYjyMoAE3yAHIyTTKQTIVYpFAUkhiR9kJsrABfB5WfyGbB5bAkOCKKD0bDiDqvMAkz5wYB2SUkdDLISwXD6EIaUaCbbAMrC0WiiVfdEOOaGkVi030vkCJksvZhBY4jSlEIwTV2a6aMnTC16RjbR0kJDATY8iEAATQWDwyE4EFw6EExwAynBMMgAMIptOsbaupYaAjYECxXAwCC0GhgECYeIkAA0iHLlercTrDabrfbVZrEG7jdkTUJbWhXR6fSGyE1SmAIswz0W0QAhOttlGo0mbDL3vIAIz5H6ITPZvOpwQEQ%20tgBMrYAzOD2jC4X02UeNnwBOfc-nBAAApYdAaEfVtYhoB8DBoW9EDJGh%20hpMl%20i5IA)

Comment: I know what I can do with decorators, but to come to your example: Is it possible to run a class-decorator (e.g. a decorator which saves the class to an internal class-map) **without** instanciating the class? I want all my class-names to be saved internally via a decorator  but I dont want to instanciate all classes every possible request... but thanks anyways for this example!

Comment: Class level decorators are run when the class gets "declared". In this moment there is a window for replacing constructors/methods, saving metadata etc...

Comment: So there is no analyzer which analyzes all classes for decorators? In conclusion: I have to call all the classes myself so this procedure cannot be made dynamic when I want to have all Classdecorators of all classes to be called before a request comes in?

Comment: As I previously said. Class level decorators are run only once. When class gets declared (not on instance creation). So you can register decorated class names even if you never constructed any instances. Ex: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true&emitDecoratorMetadata=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAMiA5gYQDYEMIQHLoLYCmMAvDABRToBOiBUAXDOmAJ4CUJAfDAN4CwAKBjCYoSCFQEAdKiRkABmkwQYYfAUYASHpRp0pawgF95bQUYDcgwQAEEKDFlyFBwRyqVYAgrxhHrAnZInjjqru4wIQBCvv4CtvYhzgThypHuyLxGQA

Comment: Thanks! And when all classes are declared in external files? So they should be imported at least?

Comment: You need to import them or at least something from the same files they're at.